# Getting exec() PHP to work like it does on the command line

Tags: php, exec, pdflatex

The following command, which generates a .pdf file from a .tex file, works from the command line but not when I run it with PHP. The file has the appropriate permissions and I'm able to run other commands with `exec()` so not sure what is going on.

```
$file_path='uploads/some-path';

$full_path='uploads/some-path/file.pdf';

$cmd ="pdflatex -output-directory ".$file_path.' '.$full_path;

exec($cmd);
```

The flag `-output-directory` place the file in the `file_path` rather than the root directory.

Comment: `exec()` has three arguments and a return value. You're discarding everything that's not mandatory.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario why do I need the other 2 arguments?

Comment: To find out what's wrong. You're probably assuming that `exec()` stops working randomly but it's never the case; you're feeding it with a specific command that does not complete successfully.

Comment: run `exec($cmd,$output,$status)` then `var_dump($output,$status)` to check your command's output and exit status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is pdflatex in the search path?  Perhaps try specifying the full path to the executable and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: `whereis pdflatex` said `/usr/bin/pdflatex`. Adding this to the command worked!!!! thanks!!!